# Angular 6 form template error: 'There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"'

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have downloaded Angular 6 + bootstrap 4 free skin - https://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-bootstrap-4-angular-6/
When trying to use 
I continuously getting error: 
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm".

My app.module.ts:

```
 import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
    import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

    import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
    import {AuthGuard} from './shared';
    import {TokenInterceptor} from './shared/authtoken';
    import {AuthService} from './shared/services/auth/auth.service';
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    // AoT requires an exported function for factories
    export const createTranslateLoader = (http: HttpClient) => {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
    };

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule,
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            }),
            AppRoutingModule
        ],
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        providers: [
            AuthGuard,
            {
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: TokenInterceptor,
                multi: true
            },
            AuthService
        ],
        exports: [
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My login.component.ts:

```
    import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    import {routerTransition} from '../router.animations';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-login',
        templateUrl: './login.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
        animations: [routerTransition()]
    })

    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

        public myform: FormGroup;
        public username: FormControl;
        public password: FormControl;

        constructor(public router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
                username: new FormControl('', [
                    Validators.minLength(4),
                    Validators.required
                ]),
                password: new FormControl('', [
                    Validators.minLength(4),
                    Validators.required
                ])
            });
        }

        async onLoggedin(form: ElementRef) {

            console.log('Start login... ' + form);
        await this.httpClient.post<AuthenticationResponse>('http://127.0.0.1:51120/login',
            {'username': this.username.value, 'password': this.password.value})
            .toPromise().then(
                data => {
                    console.log('Successfully logged in with user name: ', data.name);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem('isLogin', 'true');
                },
                error => {
                    if (!error.ok) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Failed login message: ', error.error.message);
                    }

                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    localStorage.removeItem('isLogin');
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                });

        return false;
    }
}

    interface AuthenticationResponse {
        status: string;
        code: string;
        message: string;
        id: number;
        token: string;
        username: string;
        role: string;
        name: string;
        companyName: string;
    }
```

My login.component.html:

```
<div class="login-page" [@routerTransition]>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="150px" class="user-avatar" />
            <h1><h1>Fish farms login</h1></h1>
            <form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onLoggedin(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
                <div class="form-content">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" required minlength="4" 
                   formControlName="username" placeholder="Username" ngModel>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" required 
                       minlength="4" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" ngModel>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Log in</button>
                    <a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Register</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All over got replies asking to add to @NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,

But it does not work for me at all.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your Template:

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onLoggedin(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

Here you're using `#f="ngForm"` which is generally used for Template Driven Forms and you're creating a Reactive Form in your TypeScript class.

You should be using either one of them but not both at the same time in the same Component.

You'll anyway have access to the form in your Component Class.

`onLoggedin` can directly access the form using `this.myform`

To fix the issue, get rid of `#f="ngForm"` from your template:

```
<div class="login-page" [@routerTransition]>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="150px" class="user-avatar" />
      <h1>
        <h1>Fish farms login</h1>
      </h1>
      <form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onLoggedin()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-content">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" required minlength="4" formControlName="username" placeholder="Username" ngModel>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" required minlength="4" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" ngModel>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Log in</button>
          <a class="btn rounded-btn" [routerLink]="['/signup']">Register</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {routerTransition} from '../router.animations';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public myform: FormGroup;
  public username: FormControl;
  public password: FormControl;

  constructor(public router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.minLength(4),
        Validators.required
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.minLength(4),
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
  }

  async onLoggedin() {

    console.log('Start login... ' + this.myform.value);
    await this.httpClient.post < AuthenticationResponse > ('http://127.0.0.1:51120/login', {
        'username': this.myform.value.username,
        'password': this.myform.value.password
      })
      .toPromise().then(
        data => {
          console.log('Successfully logged in with user name: ', data.name);
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
          localStorage.setItem('isLogin', 'true');
        },
        error => {
          if (!error.ok) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
          } else {
            console.log('Failed login message: ', error.error.message);
          }

          localStorage.removeItem('token');
          localStorage.removeItem('isLogin');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        });

    return false;
  }
}

interface AuthenticationResponse {
  status: string;
  code: string;
  message: string;
  id: number;
  token: string;
  username: string;
  role: string;
  name: string;
  companyName: string;
}
```

Comment: Getting rid of it will prevent me to add validations.

Comment: @SharonSofer, you've already added the minLength and required validators on the form. You can simply check for the form state in the template. Like a said, you're not correctly using either Template Driven or Reactive Form.

Comment: I believe my case is that I want to add directives like:  
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username">
Same as for <form> but Angular not recognizing it even though I am adding to @NgModule the required dependency.

Comment: I am positive it is something with the downloaded skin. When I;'e created  a new Angular 6 project I could easily use <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username">